# shell script find file older than x days and delete them if they were not listet in log files

Tags: bash, shell, find, sh

I am a newbie to scripting and i need a little shell script doing the following:

1. find all .txt files they are older than x days
2. delete them if they were not listed in logfiles (textfiles and gzipped textfiles)

I know the basics about `find -mtime`, `grep`, `zgrep`, etc., but it is very tricky for me to get this in a working script.

I tried something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh
for file in $(find /test/ -iname '*.txt')
  do
  echo "$file" ls -l "$file"
  echo $(grep $file /test/log/log1)
done
```

Comment: What did you do up to now and with what results?

Comment: it tried something like this #! /bin/sh

for file in $(find /test/ -iname '*.txt'); do
       echo "$file"
       ls -l "$file"
       echo $(grep $file /test/log/log1)
done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IFS='
'
for i in `find /test/ -ctime +10`; do 
    grep -q $i log || echo $i   # replace echo with rm if satisfied
done
```

- Sets *Internal field separator* for the cases with spaces in
  filenames.
- Finds all files older than 10 days in `/test/` folder.
- Greps path in `log` file.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# $1 is the number of days

log_files=$(ls /var/log)

files=$(find -iname "*.rb" -mtime -$1)

for f in $files; do
  found="false"
  base=$(basename $f)
  for logfile in $log_files; do
    res=$(zgrep $base $logfile)
    if [ "x$res" != "x" ]; then
      found="true"
      rm $f
    fi
    if [ "$found" = "true" ]; then
      break
    fi
  done
done
```

and call it:

```
#> ./find_and_delete.sh 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a small bash script that checks whether a file is in the logs or not:

```
$ cat ~/bin/checker.sh 
#!/usr/bin/env bash
n=$(basename $1)
grep -q $n $2
$ chmod +x ~/bin/checker.sh
```

And then use it in a single `find` command:

```
$ find . -type f ! -exec ./checker.sh {} log \; -exec echo {} \;
```

This should print only the files to be deleted. Once convinced that it does what you want:

```
$ find . -type f ! -exec ./checker.sh {} log \; -exec rm {} \;
```

deletes them.